# How to create cv::RotatedRect from two cv::Point2f?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have two *cv::Point2f* points, representing the top left and bottom right corners of a rectangle.

Is there a simple way in OpenCV to create [`cv::RotatedRect`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) from them ?

Comment: you can't. it either needs 4 points, or 2 points and size + angle

Comment: and if I have 4 points, how would I do it ?

Comment: just call the constructor (for both solutions)

Comment: there is no constructor taking four points.

Comment: aww, sorry. 3 not 4 points, seems i can't count ;)

Comment: Are you looking at the c++ Opencv API ? Because I can't find a 3 points constructor either.

Comment: hmm, you're right . it's 3.0 feature only. sorry again.

Comment: Sorry, but I got lost here. How many points do you have? :) In the 4-point case, do you know the correspondence between each point - corner?

Comment: I understand that it is not possible with two points. I have now the four points of the rectangle and I know their positions. With these four points, I'd like to construct a RotatedRect in the easiest possible way, but apparently, I have to compute the angle and Size by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no RotatedRect constructor from two corner points (as in cv::Rect) precisely because **we need to know the rotation** angle.

If we assume this is a 'straight' rectangle we can do something like:

```
Point a(0,0);   // corner point A
Point b(10,10); // corner point B
float angle = 0.f;


RotatedRect rr(0.5*(a+b), // center 
               Size2f((float)fabs(a.x-b.x),fabs(a.y-b.y)), // size
               angle);
```

As you see this is not as "simple" as in the cv::Rect case though.

Comment: How can i get the Angle that it is rotated when I have Rect(x1,y1,x2-x1,y2-y1) ?